# Difference between Umbraco NuGet Packages

Tags: umbraco, nuget-package

I was wondering if someone could explain the differences between the Umbraco Cms Core Binaries Package and Umbraco Cms NuGet Package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good question. First I would recommend the Umbraco community site for questions and answers over at http://our.umbraco.org

The main Umbraco.Cms NuGet package includes the main Umbraco CMS for it to run and has a dependendcy on the Umbraco.Cms.Core Binaries Nuget package for it to work.

If you were to build a custom extenion or package for Umbraco, you may not need the main CMS but just the need that DLLs that ship with Umbraco so you can develop against the API.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Warren :)

Comment: Thanks Warren! Confirmed my suspicions was just surprised in the latest Umbraco Version Core Binaries had more downloads than the main Umbraco CMS